# How to get the chrome tabs to always show when in full screen mode?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fullscreen, tabs

I would really like to use Chrome on my new 2013 Macbook Air with tabs, but without the menu bar.  So, I use full-screen mode, but it hides the tabs.  Is what I want possible?  And, if so, how can I get it to work that way?

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/184815/show-tabs-in-chrome-full-screen-mode

Answer (score 303):

With latest version of Chrome, there is the option to show the Toolbar (which includes tabs) in the `View` menu.

[image]

Answer (score 60):

Shift-CMD-F is for presentation mode and will hide the tabs.  You want full screen mode instead, so use Control-CMD-F.  Tabs will show in full screen mode.

Comment: This does not appear to work in the latest versions of Chrome or OS X, except in conjunction with [the other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254570/176657).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: A note to this command: it is working only if already in full screen mode. This command toggles Tabs bar in full screen mode. Just tried in Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit), Mac 10.12.6

Comment: Ahhh I see what happened - Shift-Cmd-F toggles tabs in fullscreen mode on and off - Ctrl-Cmd-F toggles fullscreen mode on and off

Comment: Shift-CMD-F worked for me. Thanks for this shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you’re trying to enter **Full Screen Mode** with `Command+Shift+F`. Like what others have mentioned, you have to use `Shift+Command+F` to enter **Full Screen Mode** (with tabs available) instead of **Presentation Mode** where tabs are hidden.

But if you want to use `Command+Shift+F` for **Full Screen** mode, open Keyboard Preferences and change Presentation Mode shortcut to other key combination, eg. `Option+Shift+F`. Here is the screenshot for the explanation above. (Ignore the All Applications configurations; just take a look at Google Chrome shortcuts assignments)

[image: Google Chrome Shortcut Overridden]

Answer (score 4):

chrome://flags, look for "Enables simplified fullscreen", make sure you set it to disabled.

Comment: Might want to add to be very certain of the actions you perform on this page.

Comment: Flag does not exist anymore

Comment: as of 2021, I've found it within "Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar" flag

Answer (score 1):

Go to **View >Enter Full Screen**.

To hide the tabs again, go to **View > Enter Presentation Mode**.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the viewing mode.  Here's [another article](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1568437) that describes the behavior in further detail.

**Presentation Mode**
Full-screen without tabs.

**Full-screen Mode**
Full-screen with tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I am dropping off the address and tabs bar with this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenhelper/odpfhihammejhokpbbkbhlmhnoipglmc

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem and had tried the solutions and did not work until I reset the display settings and changed the scaled size. I used the apple display monitor settings.